# Define foreign key for ICollection in Entity Framework model

Tags: c#, model, reference, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

How to define in `Entity Framework 6`, which columns will be used to reference data in an `ICollection<>`?

For example, we have a simple User-Information relation, were i can get all information from a user which updated or created the information:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId
    {
        get;
        get;
    }

    // Here is the problem, how to define that EF
    // Has to use the CreateUser column
    public virtual ICollection<User> User_CreateUser
    {
        get;
        set;
    }   

    // Here is the problem, how to define that EF
    // Has to use the UpdateUser column
    public virtual ICollection<User> User_UpdateUser
    {
        get;
        set;
    }   
}

public class Information
{
    public int InfoId
    {
        get;
        set;            
    }   

    public int CreateUser
    {
        get;
        set;            
    }

    public int UpdateUser
    {
        get;
        set;            
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ForeignKey("CreateUser")]
    public virtual User User_CreateUser
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ForeignKey("UpdateUser")]
    public virtual User User_UpdateUser
    {
        get;
        set;
    }       
}
```

But i don't know, how to map this. For the simple foreign-keys it was easy over annotations.

I use database first but generating the models on my own. (Which works pretty good besides the `ICollection<>`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You've marked your second foreign key as `User` but it should be `int`.

```
public int UpdateUser { get; set; }
```

Try this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Test
{
    public class User
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<User> User_CreateUser { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<User> User_UpdateUser { get; set; }
    }

    public class Information
    {
        public int InfoId { get; set; }

        public int CreateUser { get; set; }

        public int UpdateUser { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CreateUser")]
        public virtual User User_CreateUser { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UpdateUser")]
        public virtual User User_UpdateUser { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was my fault becuase i wrote the code for the SO question. But this did not solve my problem :D

Comment: @BendEg but it should :) Problem lies somewhere else then. Does it throw some exceptions?

Comment: Ok, maybe the question has a bad description. I mean, how does the Entity Framework map `User_CreateUser` to `CreateUser` and `User_UpdateUser` to `UpdateUser`? Over the name?

Comment: @BendEg If POCO contains only one such type EF follows "convention over configuration" and just does it. In your case (more than one similar type) you have to manually place `ForeignKey` attributes (like you did) or override `OnModelCreating` method and map columns there.

Comment: Ok, so ForeignKey  also work on one to many? That's the important information, thank you!